# CompletionHandler Start Conditional Action - Swift IOS

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-social-plugins

I have a facebook post code as below with the social framework. I need a conditional action to start after clicking on cancel or post in the facebook share view. In my current code below, the function starts even if cancel or post is clicked. I need it only to start when post is clicked. I couldn't found a way to get the output of the variable "resutl". Any ideas?

```
      shareToFacebook.completionHandler = {
        (result:SLComposeViewControllerResult) in

        println(result)
         println(SLComposeViewControllerResult)


        self.postActivityFunc()
    }

    self.presentViewController(shareToFacebook, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it like this inside your completionHandler block

```
var getResult = result as SLComposeViewControllerResult;
switch(getResult.toRaw()) {
case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Cancelled.toRaw(): println("User cancelled post")
case SLComposeViewControllerResult.Done.toRaw(): println("User posted")
```

Comment: Thank you again Rajatp :) you are great